# Unmarshal dynamic JSON based on a type key

Tags: json, go

I'm looking for a solution which DOESN'T involve introducing an additional "generic" field like `Value`, `Data`, etc. which would  be a placeholder for the variant field.

I have a JSON spec which describes several large structs, which hold mostly simple values, but occasionally a value which is a struct itself, with a dynamic type depending on the value of a certain field.

For example, both these JSON documents should unmarshal to the same Go struct:

```
{ 
  "some_data": "foo",
  "dynamic_field": { "type": "A", "name": "Johnny" },
  "other_data": "bar"
}
```

and

```
{
  "some_data": "foo",
  "dynamic_field": { "type": "B", "address": "Somewhere" },
  "other_data": "bar"
}
```

The JSON structure is set, I can't change it.

The Go struct must look like this:

```
type BigStruct struct {
  SomeData     string    `json:"some_data"`
  DynamicField Something `json:"dynamic_field"`
  OtherData    string    `json:"other_data"`
}
```

The question is how to actually do it and what that `Something` type should be.

I've started by making it an interface:

```
type Something interface {
  GetType() string
}
```

And have several structs and funcs to go with it:

```
type BaseDynamicType struct {
  Type string `json:"type"`
}

type DynamicTypeA struct {
  BaseDynamicType
  Name string `json:"name"`
}

type DynamicTypeB struct {
  BaseDynamicType
  Address string `json:"address"`
}

func (d *BaseDynamicType) GetType() string {
  return d.Type
}
```

The reason is, that when I get an instance of `BigStruct`, I can do this:

```
switch big.DynamicField.GetType() {
  case "A": // do something with big.DynamicField cast to DynamicTypeA
  case "B": // do something with big.DynamicField cast to DynamicTypeB
}
```

However, then I got stuck - how could this arrangement work with `UnmarshalJSON`? I think that `BigStruct` should implement `UnmarshalJSON` which would somehow inspect the `Type` field of the `dynamic_field` and then based on it, make `DynamicField` either a `DynamicTypeA` or `DynamicTypeB`.

But how? One way which probably doesn't work because of recursion would be:

- Mark `DynamicField` as `json:"-"`
- Implement `UnmarshalJSON` for BigStruct
- unmarshal the JSON into a `map[string]interface{}` in the `BigStruct`'s `UnmarshalJSON`,
- inspect the `dynamic_field` value in the map, manually construct either `DynamicTypeA` or `DynamicTypeB`
- unmarshal the same data again into `BigStruct`
- fixup the `DynamicField` with the manually created values

... but that will lead to infinite recursion in the 5th step when I try to unmarshal the data into a `BigStruct` which would call the same `UnmarshalJSON` function which is currently executing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
type BigStruct struct {
    SomeData     string      `json:"some_data"`
    DynamicField DynamicType `json:"dynamic_field"`
    OtherData    string      `json:"other_data"`
}

type DynamicType struct {
    Value interface{}
}

func (d *DynamicType) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var typ struct {
        Type string `json:"type"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &typ); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch typ.Type {
    case "A":
        d.Value = new(TypeA)
    case "B":
        d.Value = new(TypeB)
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, d.Value)

}

type TypeA struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type TypeB struct {
    Address string `json:"address"`
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/oKMKQTdzp7s

---

If you don't want to, or can't, change the type of the DynamicField you can put the UnmarshalJSON method on the BigStruct and declare a temporary type to avoid recursion.

```
func (b *BigStruct) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var typ struct {
        DF struct {
            Type string `json:"type"`
        } `json:"dynamic_field"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &typ); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    switch typ.DF.Type {
    case "A":
        b.DynamicField = new(DynamicTypeA)
    case "B":
        b.DynamicField = new(DynamicTypeB)
    }

    type tmp BigStruct // avoids infinite recursion
    return json.Unmarshal(data, (*tmp)(b))
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/at5Okp3VU2u

Comment: Thanks, I've also found that variant, but it requires modifying the structures to create the `Value` field which isn't in the original structures, so I can't use the approach.

Comment: @IvanVoras Then put UnmarshalJSON on BigStruct like you outlined in your question and to avoid the recursion issue, you can declare a new temporary type inside the UnmarshalJSON and then convert it into BigStruct.

Comment: @IvanVoras I've extended the answer by adding a solution that better complies with your requirements.

Comment: Cool, that's a nice approach! Thanks!

Comment: @mkopriva   How does `UnmarshalJSON` method gets called? This looks like magic to me especially since there are no explicit calls to that method. Please explain someone. That will be some learning for me.

Comment: @rickydj It is [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) that invokes that method. The docs say: *"To unmarshal JSON into a value implementing the Unmarshaler interface, Unmarshal **calls that value's UnmarshalJSON** method, including when the input is a JSON null."*

Comment: The problem here I see is that go never "knows" (the editor intellisense too) if DynamicField actually has the name or address values on it. You need to then jump through additional hoops to coerce or tell go that indeed, _this_ one is `DynamicTypeA`, and _this_ one is `DynamicTypeB`, i.e.: https://play.golang.com/p/7ck36wnmPiz